# Laravel update parent of parent updated_at timestamp

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to update a parent of a parents updated_at timestamp when the child model is updated. I can updated the parent model using the following code inside the child model

```
protected $touches = ['post']
```

but for example if I also wanted to update the user who made the posts updated_at timestamp how would I do this?

I was hoping I could just add the following code to the Post.php model

```
protected $touches = ['user']
```

but this doesn't seem to work, the user model timestamp only gets updated if the Post record is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures) could help you?...

**Post.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::updated(function ($post) {
            $post->user->touch();
        });
    }
}
```

This is assuming that your Post has a User relationship defined.

Here we are listening for the `updated` event on the `Post`. When that event is triggered, the associated `User` is touched.

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented an observer for the Post model which updates the timestamps :)